# How to fix Ionic NullInjectorError while using the google maps API with a toggle button?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a project where I use the Google Maps API with Ionic and I want to create a toggle where you can switch between satellite view and street view with the toggle on and off. This is something I've been stuck on for quite some time and I believe this issue is caused by the way I'm importing the SearchPage and using map, but any feedback would be appreciated.

Error Message:

```
VM67048 vendor.js:62134 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(SearchPageModule)[SearchPage -> SearchPage -> SearchPage -> SearchPage]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for SearchPage!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(SearchPageModule)[SearchPage -> SearchPage -> SearchPage -> SearchPage]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for SearchPage!
    at NullInjector.get (VM58879 vendor.js:67026)
    at R3Injector.get (VM58879 vendor.js:67193)
    at R3Injector.get (VM58879 vendor.js:67193)
    at R3Injector.get (VM58879 vendor.js:67193)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (VM58879 vendor.js:81247)
    at R3Injector.get (VM58879 vendor.js:67193)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (VM58879 vendor.js:81247)
    at Object.get (VM58879 vendor.js:80961)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (VM58879 vendor.js:59313)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (VM58879 vendor.js:59425)
    at resolvePromise (VM58874 polyfills.js:3445)
    at VM58874 polyfills.js:3352
    at rejected (VM58879 vendor.js:100902)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (VM58874 polyfills.js:3011)
    at Object.onInvoke (VM58879 vendor.js:84501)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (VM58874 polyfills.js:3010)
    at Zone.run (VM58874 polyfills.js:2770)
    at VM58874 polyfills.js:3504
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (VM58874 polyfills.js:3046)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (VM58879 vendor.js:84488)
```

For example, here is my HTLM code for the toggle button (which is inside a fab button):

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item><ion-text style="color: blue;">Satellite View</ion-text><ion-toggle (ionChange)="update($event)" color="primary" md="md"></ion-toggle></ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Here is the ts code for the update() function:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {SearchPage} from "../search/search.page"
@Component({
selector: 'app-accessibility-popover',
templateUrl: './accessibility-popover.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./accessibility-popover.component.scss'],
})
export class AccessibilityPopoverComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private searchpage: SearchPage) { }

ngOnInit() {}


update(event)
{
  if (event.detail.checked == true)
  {
     searchpage.Test.map.setMapTypeId('terrain');

  }
  console.log(event.detail.checked);
}

 }
```

here is the code for the searchpage, which actually has all the code for the api and displays the map:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';


declare var google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.page.scss'],
})
export class SearchPage implements OnInit {

  map: any;
  @ViewChild('map', {read: ElementRef, static: false}) mapRef: ElementRef;
  infoWindows: any = [];
  markers: any = [
    {
      title: "Building1",
      latitude: "33.646479464261766",
      longitude: "-117.84011195587281"
    }
  ];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.showMap();
  }

  addMarkersToMap(markers) {
    for (let marker of markers) {
      let position = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude);
      let mapMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        title: marker.title,
        latitude: marker.latitude,
        longitude: marker.longitude
      });

      mapMarker.setMap(this.map);
      this.addInfoWindowToMarker(mapMarker);
    }
  }
  addInfoWindowToMarker(marker) {
    let infoWindowContent = '<div id="content">' +
                              '<h2 id="firstHeading" class"firstHeading">' + marker.title + '</h2>' +
                              '<p>Latitude: ' + marker.latitude + '</p>' +
                              '<p>Longitude: ' + marker.longitude + '</p>' +
                            '</div>';
    let infoWindow = new google.maps.infoWindow({
      content: infoWindowContent

    });

    marker.addListener('click', () => {
      this.closeAllInfoWindows();
      infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
    });
    this.infoWindows.push(infoWindow);
  }

  closeAllInfoWindows() {
    for(let window of this.infoWindows) {
      window.close();
    }
  }

  showMap() {
    const location = new google.maps.LatLng(33.64601498874652, -117.84279416485856);
    const options = {
      center: location,
      zoom: 17,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    }
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapRef.nativeElement, options);
  }
  changeMap() {
    this.map.setMapTypeId('terrain');
    
  }



  
}
```

Comment: SearchPage is a component, and you are trying to instantiate it as a service.

Comment: So how would I access the map variable outside of the file? @Tejeshree

Comment: Depends on what is the relationship between both components. If they are directly related, you can use Input/output, else you could set some property in a service that can be shared between them and fetch it from your component